# I am grtting HTTP error while opening chrome browser using undetected_chromedriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, http-error

I am getting HTTP 404 error while opening chrome browser using undetected chrome browser in selenium.
The code was running well one day and suddenly it stopped working, I have tried reinstalling undetected_chromedriver and selenium both but it is not working.

Here is part of the code I am using in jupyter notebook

```
[Cell 1]
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from undetected_chromedriver import ChromeOptions

[Cell 2]
chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")

driver = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 10
      7 chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
      8 chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
---> 10 driver = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
     11 driver.maximize_window()
     12 wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)

File d:\venv\lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py:258, in Chrome.__init__(self, options, user_data_dir, driver_executable_path, browser_executable_path, port, enable_cdp_events, desired_capabilities, advanced_elements, keep_alive, log_level, headless, version_main, patcher_force_close, suppress_welcome, use_subprocess, debug, no_sandbox, user_multi_procs, **kw)
    251 self.patcher = Patcher(
    252     executable_path=driver_executable_path,
    253     force=patcher_force_close,
    254     version_main=version_main,
    255     user_multi_procs=user_multi_procs,
    256 )
    257 # self.patcher.auto(user_multiprocess = user_multi_num_procs)
--> 258 self.patcher.auto()
    260 # self.patcher = patcher
    261 if not options:

File d:\venv\lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\patcher.py:178, in Patcher.auto(self, executable_path, force, version_main, _)
    176 self.version_main = release.version[0]
    177 self.version_full = release
--> 178 self.unzip_package(self.fetch_package())
    179 return self.patch()

File d:\venv\lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\patcher.py:287, in Patcher.fetch_package(self)
    284     download_url %= (self.version_full.vstring, self.platform_name, zip_name)
    286 logger.debug("downloading from %s" % download_url)
--> 287 return urlretrieve(download_url)[0]

File C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py:247, in urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
    230 """
    231 Retrieve a URL into a temporary location on disk.
    232 
   (...)
    243 data file as well as the resulting HTTPMessage object.
    244 """
    245 url_type, path = _splittype(url)
--> 247 with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
    248     headers = fp.info()
    250     # Just return the local path and the "headers" for file://
    251     # URLs. No sense in performing a copy unless requested.

File C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py:222, in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220 else:
    221     opener = _opener
--> 222 return opener.open(url, data, timeout)

File C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py:531, in OpenerDirector.open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    529 for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    530     meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531     response = meth(req, response)
    533 return response

File C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py:640, in HTTPErrorProcessor.http_response(self, request, response)
    637 # According to RFC 2616, "2xx" code indicates that the client's
    638 # request was successfully received, understood, and accepted.
    639 if not (200 <= code < 300):
--> 640     response = self.parent.error(
    641         'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    643 return response

File C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py:569, in OpenerDirector.error(self, proto, *args)
    567 if http_err:
    568     args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 569     return self._call_chain(*args)

File C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py:502, in OpenerDirector._call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    500 for handler in handlers:
    501     func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 502     result = func(*args)
    503     if result is not None:
    504         return result

File C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py:649, in HTTPDefaultErrorHandler.http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    648 def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649     raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

I have tried reinstalling undected_chromedriver and selenium both but is is not working

Comment: The code sample at the top of your question only has four lines, but the error traceback says the error happens on line 10.  So what is your actual code??

Comment: Here, it is like this, I am using jupyter notebook so I have also added cell number, can you help please?, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and temporarily fixed it thanks to [this](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues/1743#issuecomment-1945971109) comment, by changing the line in the patcher.py (in your case located at *d:\venv\lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\patcher.py*) from

```
download_url = "https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/%s/%s/%s"
```

to

```
download_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/%s/%s/%s"
```